# MySQL Config on Mac

Tags: mysql

I have a MacBook pro with 2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and 4GB DDR3 ram.

I am running a huge database on my laptop with over 100 million records.

I want to know : Which of the .cnf files is suitable for MySQL on my MacBook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used MySQL on a Mac, but I have for Windows.

The Windows version of MySQL came with my-medium.ini, my-small.ini, my-large.ini, my-huge.ini.

If the Mac version of MySQL came with similar .cnf files, I would choose my-medium.cnf

Once you copy my-medium.cnf to my.cnf, you could tune it as follows:

If the majority of your data is MyISAM do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CEILING(SumNDXs/POWER(1024,2)),'M') KeyBufferSize
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(index_length) SumNDXs
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')
    AND engine = 'MyISAM'
) A;
```

This will give you the proper size for key_buffer_size given the amount of MyISAM data you have. Obviously, if this number exceeds 1024M (1GB,25% of system RAM), then set key_buffer_size to your liking with good judgment, as long as it's less than 1024M.

If the majority of your data in InnoDB do this

```
SELECT CONCAT(CEILING(InnoDBDataAndIndexes/POWER(1024,2)),'M') KeyBufferSize
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) InnoDBDataAndIndexes FROM
    information_schema.tables WHERE engine = 'InnoDB'
) A;
```

This will give you the proper size for innodb_buffer_pool_size given the amount of InnoDB data and indexes you have. Obviously, if this number exceeds 3072M (3GB,75% of system RAM), then set innodb_buffer_pool_size to your liking with good judgment, as long as it's less than 3072M.

If you have a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM data, then strike a balance between these numbers and leave at least 25% of system RAM free for MacOS.

Once you have innodb_buffer_pool_size, set innodb_log_file_size to 25% of innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Then do three 3 things:

1. Shutdown mysql
2. delete ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1
3. Startup mysql (mysqld process will recreate ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 to new size)

Give it a try, and let us know !!!

Comment: thanx for your replay. Mac configs are as the same as windows'. I executed the InnoDB query you wrote here but I got an error : "ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'CEILING'".

Comment: @AliBZ Thanks you, I changed the queries. There should have been an extra right parenthesis after POWER(1024,2) in both queries.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA thanx man, I ran the query and I got 16349M ! How is it !? :D

Comment: @AliBZ All it means is that you have almost 16G of InnoDB (data and Indexes combined). This being the case, I recommend you use your judgement. With 4GB total RAM, I suggest setting innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G and innodb_log_file_size=256M for now and see how mysqld behaves.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Thanx for your replay. I checked activity monitor which is mac's task manager and mysql takes up to 2.5 GB of my RAM. I usually don't do other tasks when I am using mysql, so it is ok that mysql takes this much of my ram. But I wanna know which of .cnf configuration is suitable for my system.

Comment: @AliBZ Choose my-medium.cnf and copy it to my.cnf. Then, check out innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_log_file_size. You may want to edit them to you liking thereafter.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA thanx, I will check it and let you know ;)